# Reviewing IIS 6.0 Logs with LogParser 2.2 for FTP logins

Tags: iis, ftp, logparser

I've been using the [Striving Life](http://strivinglife.com/words/post/Using-Log-Parser-to-find-users-accounts-used-to-log-into-an-FTP-site.aspx) website for his IIS FTP LogParser 2.2 queries. My only issue is that I can't seem to combine the two queries that bring back both successful login AND their account name.  Can anyone help?

- This brings back the users that have logged in

  logparser "select cs-uri-stem, count(cs-method) from ex*.log where cs-method like '%USER' group by cs-uri-stem order by count(cs-method),cs-uri-stem"
- This brings back  all of the successful logins by IP

  logparser "select c-ip, count(sc-status) from ex*.log where sc-status = '230' group by c-ip order by count(sc-status),c-ip"

As I said, I would like to have the best of both worlds.  Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay.

So let's break it up into it's smaller parts, based upon what data we want and that we're looking at.

That gives us the following as a base:

```
logparser "select cs-uri-stem, cs-method, c-ip from \\192.168.1.104\wwwroot\ex*.log"
```

Based on our conditions, we have the following then:

```
logparser "select cs-uri-stem, cs-method, c-ip, sc-status from \\192.168.1.104\wwwroot\ex*.log where cs-method like '%USER'"

logparser "select cs-uri-stem, cs-method, c-ip, sc-status from \\192.168.1.104\wwwroot\ex*.log where sc-status = '230'"
```

Now if you do this you can see the problem; cs-method like '%USER' returns a sc-status of 331, so if we attempt to combine them, that just isn't going to work.

Status code 230 is 'user has logged in, proceed' - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318380 - while 331 is just saying the username is okay.

So let's step back and actually look at a log for when a user logs in. The cs-username, since they're authenticated, will be populated with the name of the account they're using.

```
logparser "select cs-username, cs-method, c-ip, sc-status from \\192.168.1.104\wwwroot\ex*.log where sc-status = '230'"
```

Which means this should be what we want:

```
logparser "select cs-username, c-ip, count(*) from \\192.168.1.104\wwwroot\ex*.log where sc-status = '230' group by cs-username, c-ip order by count(*), cs-username, c-ip"
```

Based on a scan of a file - http://media.jamesrskemp.com/articles/IIS6FTPSample.log.txt - that looks to be correct.

Does that help?

---

And looking at my post again, the key part that was missed was that the first helps "determine what user names were used to login, **or attempt to login**, to an FTP site." If you search for FTPUser3 in my sample log above, you'll see a 331 is returned by IIS, even though I didn't create the FTPUser3 account. Seemingly for security purposes, it seems IIS 6 FTP returns 331 either way.

Comment: I don't actually know if you could have been MORE helpful. Thank you.